# Why does my Ruby test return only one word instead of the entire auth_name string?

Tags: arrays, ruby, rspec

Here is the code I have:

```
def initialize (htaccess_file_content)
   @htaccess_hash = Hash.new
   htaccess_file_content.each_line do | line |
      @commands = line.split
      @htaccess_hash[@commands[0]] = @commands[1]
   end
end
def auth_name
  @htaccess_hash['AuthName'].gsub(/''/,"")
end
```

This is my spec:

```
describe WebServer::Htaccess do
  let(:auth_name) { "This is the auth_name" }
end

describe '#auth_name' do
  it 'returns the AuthName string' do
    expect(htaccess_user.auth_name).to eq auth_name
  end
end
```

My Ruby code is not returning the whole string and I don't know why. Here is the error message from the failed test:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(htaccess_user.auth_name).to eq auth_name

   expected: "This is the auth_name"
        got: "\"This"

   (compared using ==)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use an Array Slice

> @htaccess_hash[@commands[0]] = @commands[1]

[String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-split) splits on whitespace by default, so when you specify `@commands[1]` you are assigning only a single array element (the word "This") as your hash value. The simplest thing you can do is to change your subscript to an [Array#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) to assign *all* the remaining elements as the hash value, e.g.:

```
@commands = line.split
@htaccess_hash[@commands[0]] = @commands[1..-1]
```

Comment: but why is it giving "/"This"?

Comment: @KevinHwang Because `@commands[1] == "This"` after the line is split on whitespace. Debug your script, and you'll see that @commands is an array, and the first element is a one-word string. Q.E.D.